# Why not @Autovired Session Factory? Java Hibernate Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I can not understand why the bean sessionFactory does not fill out. Why is this happening?

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

      <context:component-scan base-package="config"/>


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

AppConfiguration in which the @Bean sessionFactory is declared:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"controllers","model","dao","service"})
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"model"});
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(datasource());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(){return new JdbcTemplate(datasource());}

    @Bean
    public DataSource datasource(){
        BasicDataSource dataSource=new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quizzes");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("dbpass");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(@Autowired SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        HibernateTransactionManager manager= new HibernateTransactionManager();
        manager.setDataSource(datasource());
        manager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return manager;
    }


}
```

A class that uses the bean sessionFactory. He is not @Autowired, as a result of which he has null:

```
@Service
public class AnswerDAOReal extends EntityDAO<Answer, Integer> {
    @Autowired SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public AnswerDAOReal() {
        session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
}
```

abstract class EntityDAO -It is the parent of classes such as: AnswerDAOReal, UserDAOReal ... XxxDAOReal

```
abstract class EntityDAO<T, Id extends Serializable> {//Wnen: T- is type of Entity, iD- Type of ID// and DAOEntity- inheritor type of DAOEntity
     SessionFactory sessionFactory;
     Session session;

     EntityDAO(){}

    public void persist(T entity) {
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(entity);
        session.flush();
        transaction.commit();
    }

    public void update(T entity) {
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(entity);
        session.flush();
        transaction.commit();
    }

    public T findById(Id id) {
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        T entity= (T) session.get(getGenericType(),id);
        session.flush();
        transaction.commit();
        return  entity;
    }

    public void delete(Id id) {
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        T entity = (T) findById(id);
        session.delete(entity);
        session.flush();
        transaction.commit();
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        List<T> collection = session.createQuery("from "+getGenericType().getSimpleName()).list();
        session.flush();
        transaction.commit();
        return collection;
    }
    public void deleteAll() {
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        List<T> entityList = findAll();
        for (T entity : entityList) {
            session.delete(entity);
        }
        session.flush();
        transaction.commit();
    }


    public Class getGenericType(){
        Class type= (Class) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
                .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        return type;
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDAOReal'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAOReal' defined in file [C:\JProjects\Hillel\SpringQuiz\out\artifacts\Servlet1_war_exploded\WEB-INF\classes\dao\UserDAOReal.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [dao.UserDAOReal]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDAOReal'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAOReal' defined in file [C:\JProjects\Hillel\SpringQuiz\out\artifacts\Servlet1_war_exploded\WEB-INF\classes\dao\UserDAOReal.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [dao.UserDAOReal]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAOReal' defined in file [C:\JProjects\Hillel\SpringQuiz\out\artifacts\Servlet1_war_exploded\WEB-INF\classes\dao\UserDAOReal.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [dao.UserDAOReal]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at dao.UserDAOReal.<init>(UserDAOReal.java:16)
```

Comment: All classes that end with "DAOReal" have the same architecture

Comment: when you try open session in constructor the sessionfactory field not yet instantiated. @Autowired will works after instance is construct.https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your autowiring seems to be wrong. You inject the property on the field but you also have a constructor that opens the session.

Firstly, I would suggest to avoid injecting the property on the field itself and I would strongly recommend a constructor injection. Secondly where is the declaration of the `session` attribute in your `AnswerDAOReal` example?

With those in mind, I would suggest the following:

- Use constructor based dependency injection. Doing it on the field is
  not the recommended way.
- Have a method annotated with `@PostConstruct` which will be
  responsible for opening your session. Using this annotation will
  guarantee that the this is going to be called right after the
  initialization of the bean that finished taking place.

An example of this would be:

```
@Service
public class AnswerDAOReal extends EntityDAO<Answer, Integer> {

    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private Session session;

    @Autowired
    public AnswerDAOReal(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void openSession() {
        this.session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

}
```

Comment: "Secondly where is the declaration of the session attribute in your AnswerDAOReal example?"
I'm using abstract class EntityDAO. It has an session attribute (added class EntityDAO to the question)

Comment: @VladislavSolopov what do you mean by `where is the declaration of the session attribute in your AnswerDAOReal example`? I think it's pretty obvious where this is declared and initialized.

Comment: Sorry for the question. abstract PostConstruct must use library: import javax.annotation.PostConstruct; ?
The compiler writes that the "annotation is not visible"

Comment: Are you importing everything correctly? Also what is that `abstract` you're mentioning about?

Comment: I just added
 abstract class EntityDAO

Comment: "Error:(12, 13) java: package javax.annotation is not visible
  (package javax.annotation is declared in module java.xml.ws.annotation, which is not in the module graph)"
Indicates the line: import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

Comment: What Java version are you using?

Comment: I use Java 9 version

Comment: You'll need to figure out what packages you'll need to import to your module. This is coming from `javax` which I think by default is not included.

Comment: Lowered the version - annotation PostConstruct began to work.
Moved constructor into class-parent and PostConstruct start work.
I am very grateful to you. Spent two days on the decision. Without you, I would spend even more time.

Comment: @VladislavSolopov happy to have helped. Just an advise though, I would suggest to read up on dependency injection and the bean life-cycle in general.